# AppEngine Specific Version HTTPS certificate error

Tags: google-app-engine, https

I'm using AppEngine with appspot.com URL.
I've notice that when I access my app using https://myapp.appspot.com everything is good and the certificate checks-out but when I use specific version URL such as https://1.myapp.appspot.com I get a warning that the certificate does not match the URL.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access other versions of your app using a URL like https://1-dot-myapp.appspot.com - '-dot-' between the version and your app-id.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons behind this are clearly defined in the docs (first note): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Instead, as @Greg mentioned, use dot notation.